# Meteor - template not updated after user sign in

Tags: meteor, meteor-accounts

I built an app with simple user login, using Accounts-unstyled. It all works fine, except that the template showing user data is not re-rendered with the user logs in. However if the user reloads the page, then his data is present.

My code doesn't really contain anything related to user, except for fetching the correct user's data. Do I need to manually trigger a refresh after the login?

The app is at [www.barelinks.in](http://www.barelinks.in). Test login: user=*test*; password=*pwdpwd*.
Upon first login nothing changes, but if you reload you will see the user's data.

Here is the code for the subscription:

```
if(Meteor.isServer) {
    Meteor.publish('links', function linksPublication(userId) {
        return Links.find({ user: userId });
    });
}
```

And the helper fetching the right data (the Regex is for the search feature):

```
Template.body.helpers({
    links: function() {
        var nbSkip = linksPerPage*(Template.instance().page.get() - 1);
        var queryRegex = new RegExp(Template.instance().query.get(), 'i');
        return Links.find({ user: Meteor.userId(), title: queryRegex }, { sort: { createdAt: -1 }, limit: linksPerPage, skip: nbSkip });
    },
});
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recognized that the content is updated when refreshing the page in a logged in state. Than you can switch forth and back and everything works as expected. I came usually across this behavior when the data subscription is not as it should be.

The server automatically updates the data according to a change of logged in state, you need to rely on the `this.user` property in the publish function.

```
if(Meteor.isServer) {
    Meteor.publish('links', function linksPublication() {
        return Links.find({ user: this.userId });
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I added the code for the subscription and the helper. Could it be because I'm running twice Links.find()?

Comment: hi no actually running that twice is by design. I am not sure about the double userId restriction on the client though you do not really need to do that, since the server is responsible for giving the right user the right data.

Comment: Yeah I realized that and amended. Still can't solve this, I think I'll progressively convert the example To Do app into this one and see where this behavior occurs.

Comment: ah one more thing i just recognized on the server you should use this.userId, the way you put it it would be a parameter to be handed over via the subscribe function.

Comment: That solved it! I would assume the problem was that the variable `userId` was not updated when login in or out.

Comment: yeah not until you would be resubscribing i guess ;) I edited the answer to be a bit more straight to the point